# mysql trigger on update: how to detect NULL values?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-trigger

I try to update the porcentageComplete profil when users updates his profile:

statut field:

```
`statut` enum('Marié','En couple','Divorcé') DEFAULT NULL,
```

Trigger is:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS update_user;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER update_user
    BEFORE UPDATE
    ON users FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE porcentage int default 0;
    IF NEW.statut!=NULL OR OLD.statut!=NULL THEN 
        set porcentage = porcentage + 1;
    END IF;
    SET NEW.porcentageCompleted = porcentage;

END$$
```

This not update correctly the porcentageCompleted : it looks like NULL comparaison does not work correctly

Comment: I did: same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparisons with `=` or `<>`(or `!=`) to a `NULL` value yield `NULL` themselves, so not true, i.e. false. Use `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` to check for `NULL`s.

```
...
IF NEW.statut IS NOT NULL
    OR OLD.statut IS NOT NULL THEN 
...
```

Worth a read: [3.3.4.6 Working with NULL Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html)

Comment: ok for NULL precision, however it does not solve my problem. I need to update the field porcentageCompleted  if statut is not null